# Генератор корректного предложения из списка слов

Tags: python, алгоритм, машинное-обучение

Следующая задача:
Необходимо в функцию передать список слов и одно слово, на выходе необходимо корректное предложение с этим словом и любыми словами из списка, например:

```
list1 = ["в", "на", "к", "погода", "улица", "солнце"]
str1 = "хорошая"
gen_pr(list1, str1)
```

Вывод:
"На улице хорошая погода" (или иное со словом "хорошая")

Нужен совет, как лучше это реализовать.
Можно реализовать с помощью цепей Маркова, генерируя и проверяя каждое предложение на list1 и str1.
Можно ли это ещё как либо реализовать?

Comment: Как показывает современный опыт развития этой умодробительной дилеммы, просто берутся большие объемы данных человеческого общения и уже из них создаются "решения", смотрите гугл переводчик, подсказки в браузерах и т.д.

Comment: А так у вас только получиться  -"На улица хорошая погода".

Comment: @СергейКох Нет, есть грамматически безошибочный вариант наподобие "хорошая улица на солнце".